# React Redux add line-through on checkbox click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add a line-through on after checking a checkbox. I'm using react and redux. The action and reducer works. I just need a way of adding this line-through when `checked` is `true` Please find the code i tried implementing this below. Thanks in advance.

/actions/items.js

```
export const CHECK_ITEM = "CHECK_ITEM"
export function checkItem(id) {
  return {
    type: CHECK_ITEM,
    id
  }
}
```

/reducers/items.js

```
case types.CHECK_ITEM:
  return state.map((item) => {
    if(item.id === action.id) {
      return Object.assign({}, item,
        {
          checked: !item.checked
       })
    }

    return item
  })
```

/components/Editor.jsx

```
  renderValue = () => {
    const onDelete = this.props.onDelete
    const onCheck = this.props.onCheck

    return (
      <div>
        {onCheck ? this.renderCheckItem() : null}
        <div onClick={this.props.onValueClick}>
          <span className='value'>{this.props.value}</span>
          {onDelete ? this.renderDelete() : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderCheckItem = () => {
    return (
      <input 
        type="checkbox"
        className='check-item checked'
        defaultChecked={false}
        onClick={this.props.onCheck}
      />
    )
  }
```

/components/Item.jsx

```
export default class Items extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {items, onEdit, onDelete, onValueClick, onCheck, isEditing} = this.props

    return (
      <ul className="items">{items.map(item =>
        <Item
          className="item"
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}>
          <Editor
            value={item.text}
            onCheck={onCheck.bind(null, item.id)}
            style={{textDecoration: item.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}
          />
        </Item>
      )}</ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically passed `item.checked` as `item` to my `Editor` component and used it like so

```
  ...
  render() {
    const {item, value, onEdit, onValueClick, isEditing, onCheck, ...props} = this.props
...
```

then in my Editor.jsx i did the following

/components/Editor.jsx

```
  renderValue = () => {
    const onDelete = this.props.onDelete
    const onCheck = this.props.onCheck
    const itemChecked = this.props.item
    const isChecked = {textDecoration: itemChecked ? 'line-through' : 'none'} 

    return (
      <div>
        {onCheck ? this.renderCheckItem() : null}
        <div onClick={this.props.onValueClick}>
          <span style={isChecked} className='value'>{this.props.value}</span>
          {onDelete && this.renderDelete()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderCheckItem = () => {
    return (
      <input 
        type="checkbox"
        className='check-item'
        defaultChecked={false}
        onClick={this.props.onCheck}
      />
    )
  }
```

/components/Items.jsx

```
export default class Items extends React.Component {
  render () {
    ...

    return (
      <ul className='items'>{items.map((item) =>
        <Item
          className='item'
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}>
          <Editor
            item={item.checked}
            isEditing={item.isEditing}
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your components to the redux store. [Here's](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#container-components) how to do it. In short you need something like:

```
export default connect(
  state => {
    return {items: state.items};
}
)(Items);
```

Where `connect` comes from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Comment: No if I connect the my Items to the store I lose my filtering in my List component. There must be another way. I'm passing items from my List already. @lukasz